# jQuery simple left and right animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I would like the arrow to move visibly to the digit and remove the text on the way back.

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/VZsG4/

```
<span class="arrow">&rarr;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="span0">zhong</span><span id="span2">1</span><span id="span3">guo</span><span id="span4">2</span>
<br />
<input type="button" id="start" value="start" />
<input type="button" id="reset" value="reset" />

var cnt = 0;
var spanLength = $("span").length;
$("#start").click(function() {
  var tId = setInterval(
    function() {
      if (cnt>spanLength-1) clearInterval(tId);
      $(".arrow").animate(
        {"right": $("#span"+(cnt+1)).position()}, "slow",
          function(){
            $("#span"+(cnt++)).hide(); // remove word
            $("#span"+(cnt++)).hide(); // remove number
            $(".arrow").animate({"left":0}); // move back
          }
      );
    },
  1000);  
});
$("#reset").click(function() {
    clearInterval(tId);
    $("span").each(function() {
        $(this).show();
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You had a few issues with your code:

- `.arrow` needs CSS with `position:relative`
- you need to animate `left` not `right` on the arrow
- you need to grab the `left` property of `position()`
- `var tId` needs to be in the broader scope
- since `.arrow` is a span, the interval was never being cleared
- you skipped `#span1` which was causing a missing element error
- `cnt = 0` needs to be added to the reset function

[**See working fiddle here →**](http://jsfiddle.net/VZsG4/13/)

```
var cnt = 0;
var spanLength = $("span").length;
var tId;
$("#start").click(function() {
  tId = setInterval(
    function() {
        if (cnt>=spanLength-1) {
            clearInterval(tId);
        } else {
          $(".arrow").animate(
            {"left": $("#span"+(cnt+1)).position().left}, "slow",
              function(){
                $("#span"+(cnt++)).hide(); // remove word
                $("#span"+(cnt++)).hide(); // remove number
                $(".arrow").animate({"left":0}); // move back
              }
          ); 
        }
    },
  1000);  
});
$("#reset").click(function() {
    clearInterval(tId);
    cnt = 0;
    $("span").each(function() {
        $(this).show();
    });    
});
```

Comment: @mVChr Great - almost. I need the arrow to go to the left of the number which is to the right of the word. It seems to go a lot further. I changed the first span to a b - http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/VZsG4/

Comment: Here's a version subtracting the width of the spans in question so the arrow is positioned in the right place: http://jsfiddle.net/VZsG4/42/

Comment: @mVChr super. I moved the arrow width outside the function  and the span calc outside the animate.

Comment: finished version looks like a balloon popping...nice.